# Snowflake connectivity by pyodbc

Tags: python, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, odbc, pyodbc

I am trying to connect to snowflake in linux by `pyodbc` in python2.7.
I have installed `snowflake-odbc-2.25.8.x86_64.rpm` on my RHEL7 box.
I have made changes in `odbc.ini` file like this:

```
[testodbc2]  
Driver      = /usr/lib64/snowflake/odbc/lib/libSnowflake.so
Description =  
server      = <MY_ACCOUNT>.snowflakecomputing.com  
#PRIV_KEY_FILE_PWD = <MY_PASSWORD>  
AUTHENTICATOR = SNOWFLAKE_JWT  
SSL=on
```

Now if uncomment  `PRIV_KEY_FILE_PWD = <MY_PASSWORD>`  in my `odbc.ini` and execute following lines

```
conn_str_1 = "DSN={};UID={};PWD={};server={};schema={};role={};warehouse={};database={};PRIV_KEY_FILE={}".format(dsn_name, 
  user, password_str, "{}.snowflakecomputing.com".format(account), schema, role, warehouse, database, private_key_location)

 conn = pyodbc.connect(conn_str_1)
```

It works. But as soon as I comment `PRIV_KEY_FILE_PWD = <MY_PASSWORD>`  in my `odbc.ini` and try to pass password from my code, like this:

```
conn_str_1 = "DSN={};UID={};PWD={};server={};schema={};role={};warehouse={};database={};PRIV_KEY_FILE={};PRIV_KEY_FILE_PWD ={}".format(dsn_name, 
  user, password_str, "{}.snowflakecomputing.com".format(account), schema, role, warehouse, database, private_key_location, MY_PASSWORD)

 conn = pyodbc.connect(conn_str_1)
```

It starts failing with Error:

> "Error: ('HY000', '[HY000] [Snowflake][Snowflake] (44) \n   Error finalize setting: Marshaling private key failed.\n   (44) (SQLDriverConnect)')"

MY_PASSWORD has ";" inside it. So I  tried to escape it by
`MY_PASSWORD = MY_PASSWORD .replace(';', '\\;')`
before passing in DSN string, still same error.

But what is surprising me that in odbc.ini - I m using password as it is  and it is working but if I pass by code in dsn string - it is Not working.

Do you think - I am missing something here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The reference](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/The-pyodbc-Module#pyodbc-functions) says the following on the connection string argument.

> This information is formatted as key/value pairs separated by semi-colons (the values can be enclosed with curly braces if necessary)

For details, see [the ODBC reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/syntax/sqldriverconnect-function?view=sql-server-ver16#comments).

So, you should add curly braces like this.

```
...
conn = pyodbc.connect("...;PRIV_KEY_FILE_PWD={{{}}}".format(..., MY_PASSWORD))
// or 
conn = pyodbc.connect(f"...;PRIV_KEY_FILE_PWD={{{MY_PASSWORD}}}")
```

Comment: I understand the usage of curly braces. But why having PRIV_KEY_FILE_PWD={{{MY_PASSWORD}}} - 3 curly braces. Why we can't have a single curly braces - PRIV_KEY_FILE_PWD={MY_PASSWORD}.

Comment: [The reference](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) says " If you need to include a brace character in the literal text, it can be escaped by doubling: {{ and }}." And ```PRIV_KEY_FILE_PWD={MY_PASSWORD}``` will give you no brace characters.

Comment: very nice  and unique detail. I did not see anybody even tried to look into it.
Thanks a ton for your answer.